# Where bazaar looks for rules file?

Tags: bazaar

On Bazaar documentation of its using with Subversion repositories:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/foreign/bzr-on-svn-projects.html
there is info in "Limited keywords support" about expansion of `$Id$`.
Where does bazaar look for such rules file? I tried `rules.bazaar` in current directory and in `[APP_DATA]\bazaar\2.0\rules.bazaar`, and added that to `bazaar.conf` but when I checkout from Subversion repository `$Id$` is not expanded.

I work on Windows, with Bazaar (bzr) 2.2.1 and Tortoise Bazaar 0.5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `bzr version` on the commandline 
and see the line that starts with "Bazaar configuration:".
You should add a file called "rules" in that directory.

Comment: Thanks, I had rules file in this directory, but I named it `rules.bazaar`.

Answer (score 2):

You should put the rules in something like:
C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Bazaar\2.0\rules

It's the directory where you have bazaar.conf.

Keyword expansion should be easier with the [keyword plugin](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/keywords-plugin.html)